# SQL - group by both bits

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL table with one bit column. If only one bit value (in my case 1) occurs in the rows of the table, how can I make a SELECT statement which shows for, example, the occurance of both bit values in the table, even if the other does not occur? This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
+----------+--------+
| IsItTrue | AMOUNT |
+----------+--------+
|     1    |   12   |
|     0    |  NULL  |
+----------+--------+
```

I already tried to google the answer but without success, as English is not my native language and I am not that familiar with SQL jargon.

Comment: Which RDBMS product are you using?

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL server v.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select IsItTrue, count(id) as Amount from 
(select IsItTrue, id from table
union
select 1 as IsItTrue, null as id
union
select 0 as IsItTrue, null as id) t
group by bool
```

Comment: true, but op didn't specified so I needed to guess an answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff I misread it. I recant, this is standard sql. +1

Comment: @BenLee Standard Sql requires a from.

Comment: @overflowed . . . You should use `union all` rather than `union`.  There is no reason to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.